# Image Carousel with Fade to Black Transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I need to make a carousel with a fade transition that goes black, or even better some dark grey color like `#2B303A`. I've found this code on the web that works perfectly, the only problem is that the fade effect is a really bright white that I don't like and it's bothering for the eyes.

How can I make it fade to black between images?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Carousel
  var vet_url = ["https://i.imgur.com/Bb39Qpp.jpg", "https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/palms_road_marking_123929_1920x1080.jpg"];
  var len = vet_url.length;
  var i = 0;

  function swapBackgrounds() {
    $("#background").animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 700, function() {
      $($("#background")).css('background-image', 'url(' + vet_url[(i + 1) % len] + ')').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 700);
    });
    i++;
  }
  setInterval(swapBackgrounds, 10000);
});
```

```css
#background {
  background-color: #2B303A;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/palms_road_marking_123929_1920x1080.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="background"></div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GiamBoscaro/ug5t7h0b/)

Comment: You might set the background color of the element. See [Using multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds).  However, it would be helpful to see a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code to help demonstrate your issue.

Comment: setting a background color doesn't work. Here a working example http://jsfiddle.net/GiamBoscaro/ug5t7h0b/

Comment: Oh I see, yes. You're setting the opacity of that element to zero. In that case, I recommend setting the `background-image` on a child element.

Comment: Uhm yeah you are right. The opacity is 0 so I see what's underneath. In this case the body. So I need to see the black color on the body, the parent element actually. It's working now! Thank you for helping me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the opacity to 0 let you see the element underneath the carousel, in this case there's nothing but the body itself. The `background-color` of the body wasn't set so it was the default white one. Setting the `background-color` to black solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it on the html element, in your test case at least.

```
html
{
 background-color:#2B303A;
}
```

Comment: It [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/ug5t7h0b/2/), but it's understandable if you don't want the entire page to be that color. Alternatively, you could use some other parent element of `#background`.

Answer (score -1):

jquery's .animate does not work with background-colors though it can work with:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color